# twitter-bootstrap: How to align bootstrap tabs in single line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the screenshot of my tabs menu[image]

But the tab menu items jumps to next line if it has more items

**Code**

```
<div class="row col-lg-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
           ......
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!--Contents goes here -->
     </div>
  </div>
```

So how can i fits all memu items into a single line??

Comment: there's not enough space, how do you want to manage them in single line?

Comment: Those menu items are dynamically generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is what we call a scrollable tabbed menu, which enables you to click the left/right arrow to navigate through multiple tabs. You will will need to use jQuery and CSS to achieve this. Here's a perfect example for you. Hopefully it's what you are after.

http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/l2ChB4vYmC

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller scroller-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></div>
  <div class="scroller scroller-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs list" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab15</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab16</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab17</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    height:50px;
}

.list {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    min-width:3000px;
    margin-left:12px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.list li{
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    color:#efefef;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.scroller {
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
  padding:7px;
  padding-top:11px;
  white-space:no-wrap;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.scroller-right{
  float:right;
}

.scroller-left {
  float:left;
}


var hidWidth;
var scrollBarWidths = 40;

var widthOfList = function(){
  var itemsWidth = 0;
  $('.list li').each(function(){
    var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    itemsWidth+=itemWidth;
  });
  return itemsWidth;
};

var widthOfHidden = function(){
  return (($('.wrapper').outerWidth())-widthOfList()-getLeftPosi())-scrollBarWidths;
};

var getLeftPosi = function(){
  return $('.list').position().left;
};

var reAdjust = function(){
  if (($('.wrapper').outerWidth()) < widthOfList()) {
    $('.scroller-right').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.scroller-right').hide();
  }

  if (getLeftPosi()<0) {
    $('.scroller-left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.item').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow');
    $('.scroller-left').hide();
  }
}

reAdjust();

$(window).on('resize',function(e){  
    reAdjust();
});

$('.scroller-right').click(function() {

  $('.scroller-left').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-right').fadeOut('slow');

  $('.list').animate({left:"+="+widthOfHidden()+"px"},'slow',function(){

  });
});

$('.scroller-left').click(function() {

    $('.scroller-right').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.scroller-left').fadeOut('slow');

    $('.list').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow',function(){

    });
});
```

Comment: yeah its worked but the tab content menu didn't displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can extend it to number of columns you needs. It requires adding a ***less*** function.

A less variable allows to set column width in grid.less file:

```
@grid-columns:              12;
```

Here is a code that i found useful to extend it to 18 columns:

```
//
// Grid system
// --------------------------------------------------

// Set the container width, and override it for fixed navbars in media queries
.container {
  .container-fixed();
}

// mobile first defaults
.row {
  .make-row();
}

// Common styles for small and large grid columns
.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-xs-13,
.col-xs-14,
.col-xs-15,
.col-xs-16,
.col-xs-17,
.col-xs-18,
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-13,
.col-sm-14,
.col-sm-15,
.col-sm-16,
.col-sm-17,
.col-sm-18,
.col-md-1,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-13,
.col-md-14,
.col-md-15,
.col-md-16,
.col-md-17,
.col-md-18,
.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg-13,
.col-lg-14,
.col-lg-15,
.col-lg-16,
.col-lg-17,
.col-lg-18 {
  position: relative;
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
}

// Extra small grid
//
// Grid classes for extra small devices like smartphones. No offset, push, or
// pull classes are present here due to the size of the target.
//
// Note that `.col-xs-12` doesn't get floated on purpose—there's no need since
// it's full-width.

.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-xs-13,
.col-xs-14,
.col-xs-15,
.col-xs-16,
.col-xs-17 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-1  { width: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-2  { width: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-3  { width: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-4  { width: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-5  { width: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-6  { width: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-7  { width: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-8  { width: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-9  { width: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-10 { width: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-11 { width: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
.col-xs-12 { width: 100%; }

// Small grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the small device range, from phones
// to tablets.
//
// Note that `.col-sm-12` doesn't get floated on purpose—there's no need since
// it's full-width.

@media (min-width: @screen-tablet) {
  .container {
    max-width: @container-tablet;
  }

.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-13,
.col-sm-14,
.col-sm-15,
.col-sm-16,
.col-sm-17 {
  float: left;
}
  .col-sm-1  { width: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-2  { width: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-3  { width: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-4  { width: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-5  { width: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-6  { width: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-7  { width: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-8  { width: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-9  { width: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-10 { width: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-11 { width: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-12 { width: percentage((12/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-13 { width: percentage((13/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-14 { width: percentage((14/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-15 { width: percentage((15/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-17 { width: percentage((16/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-17 { width: percentage((17/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-18 { width: 100%; }

  // Push and pull columns for source order changes
  .col-sm-push-1  { left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-2  { left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-3  { left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-4  { left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-5  { left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-6  { left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-7  { left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-8  { left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-9  { left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-10 { left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-push-11 { left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  .col-sm-pull-1  { right: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-2  { right: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-3  { right: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-4  { right: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-5  { right: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-6  { right: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-7  { right: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-8  { right: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-9  { right: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-10 { right: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-pull-11 { right: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  // Offsets
  .col-sm-offset-1  { margin-left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-2  { margin-left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-3  { margin-left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-4  { margin-left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-5  { margin-left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-6  { margin-left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-7  { margin-left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-8  { margin-left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-9  { margin-left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-10 { margin-left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-sm-offset-11 { margin-left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
}

// Medium grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the desktop device range.
//
// Note that `.col-md-12` doesn't get floated on purpose—there's no need since
// it's full-width.

@media (min-width: @screen-desktop) {
  .container {
    max-width: @container-desktop;
  }
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12,
  .col-md-13,
  .col-md-14,
  .col-md-15,
  .col-md-16,
  .col-md-17 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1  { width: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-2  { width: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-3  { width: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-4  { width: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-5  { width: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-6  { width: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-7  { width: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-8  { width: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-9  { width: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-10 { width: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-11 { width: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-12 { width: percentage((12/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-13 { width: percentage((13/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-14 { width: percentage((14/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-15 { width: percentage((15/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-17 { width: percentage((16/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-17 { width: percentage((17/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-18 { width: 100%; }

  // Push and pull columns for source order changes
  .col-md-push-0  { left: auto; }
  .col-md-push-1  { left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-2  { left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-3  { left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-4  { left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-5  { left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-6  { left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-7  { left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-8  { left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-9  { left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-10 { left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-11 { left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  .col-md-pull-0  { right: auto; }
  .col-md-pull-1  { right: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-2  { right: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-3  { right: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-4  { right: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-5  { right: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-6  { right: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-7  { right: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-8  { right: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-9  { right: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-10 { right: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-11 { right: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  // Offsets
  .col-md-offset-0  { margin-left: 0; }
  .col-md-offset-1  { margin-left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-2  { margin-left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-3  { margin-left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-4  { margin-left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-5  { margin-left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-6  { margin-left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-7  { margin-left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-8  { margin-left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-9  { margin-left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-10 { margin-left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-11 { margin-left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
}

// Large grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the large desktop device range.
//
// Note that `.col-lg-12` doesn't get floated on purpose—there's no need since
// it's full-width.

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-desktop) {
  .container {
    max-width: @container-lg-desktop;
  }

  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12,
  .col-lg-13,
  .col-lg-14,
  .col-lg-15,
  .col-lg-16,
  .col-lg-17 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1  { width: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-2  { width: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-3  { width: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-4  { width: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-5  { width: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-6  { width: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-7  { width: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-8  { width: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-9  { width: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-10 { width: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-11 { width: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-12 { width: percentage((12/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-13 { width: percentage((13/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-14 { width: percentage((14/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-15 { width: percentage((15/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-16 { width: percentage((16/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-17 { width: percentage((17/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-18 { width: 100%; }

  // Push and pull columns for source order changes
  .col-lg-push-0  { left: auto; }
  .col-lg-push-1  { left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-2  { left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-3  { left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-4  { left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-5  { left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-6  { left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-7  { left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-8  { left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-9  { left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-10 { left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-push-11 { left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  .col-lg-pull-0  { right: auto; }
  .col-lg-pull-1  { right: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-2  { right: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-3  { right: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-4  { right: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-5  { right: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-6  { right: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-7  { right: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-8  { right: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-9  { right: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-10 { right: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-pull-11 { right: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  // Offsets
  .col-lg-offset-0  { margin-left: 0; }
  .col-lg-offset-1  { margin-left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-2  { margin-left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-3  { margin-left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-4  { margin-left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-5  { margin-left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-6  { margin-left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-7  { margin-left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-8  { margin-left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-9  { margin-left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-10 { margin-left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-lg-offset-11 { margin-left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
}
```